# Query for students passed and not passed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

How to make a query to know whether a student passed or not, where each student has ten subjects and the pass grade for each subject is `(>49)`
Student to be passed, he/she has to pass in all the subjects.
Any help please ?

Comment: Create a `GROUP BY` query which computes the count of failed subjects for each student: `Count(IIf([grade]>49,Null,1)` The students who passed are those for whom that count equals zero.

Comment: @HansUp, 
Thank you a lot.
Kindly, where I have to put this code ? 
in the criteria field ?

Comment: Can you create a `GROUP BY` query in the Access query designer?  I intended that `Count` expression to be in the query's `SELECT` clause --- the list of field expressions which appear as columns in the query results.  Afterward, you will reference that field expression in the column's criteria box and input `0` there.  Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I can do it, but not writing sql code . Can I ? if so, in which field i have to put your expression. I have created a query consists of studentID, StudentName and Grade. Then, i set the groupBy for  StudentID, StudentName to "last", and for the Grade to count. In the grade criteria i wrote <49. However , it return each students as 0

Comment: You can switch the query from Design View to SQL View and modify the statement details there.  If you get stuck, copy the SQL statement text from there into your question and explain how its results differ from what you need.  If your attempt triggers an error message, please include the full message in your question.

Comment: By the way, I didn't balance the parentheses in the `Count` expression I suggested earlier.  It should be: `Count(IIf([grade]>49,Null,1))`

Comment: this the sql code of my query. SELECT QueryTotalGraedFirstCourse.StudentsID, Count(QueryTotalGraedFirstCourse.Total) AS CountOfTotal
FROM QueryTotalGraedFirstCourse
GROUP BY QueryTotalGraedFirstCourse.StudentsID
HAVING (((Count(QueryTotalGraedFirstCourse.Total))<=49));. So where should i put your expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` query to count the number of subject failures for each student:

```sql
Count(IIf(q.Total > 49, Null, 1))
```

Ultimately you want to see only the students who have passed all their subjects, which means their count of failures is zero.  So include that condition in the query's `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT
    q.StudentsID,
    Count(IIf(q.Total > 49, Null, 1)) AS CountOfFailures
FROM QueryTotalGraedFirstCourse AS q
GROUP BY q.StudentsID
HAVING Count(IIf(q.Total > 49, Null, 1)) = 0;
```

You can start building this query in the Access query designer's Design View.  Specify your table, select the fields, and set up the basic `GROUP BY` details in Design View.  Then you can switch to SQL View to include the `IIf` expression in the `Count`.

Here is my sample data for *QueryTotalGraedFirstCourse*.  To keep it simple I only included 2 subjects per student.

```
StudentsID subject_id Total
---------- ---------- -----
         1          1    90
         1          2    85
         2          1    65
         2          2    30
         3          1    40
         3          2    35
```

Based on your description, "passed" means no failing score for any subject, so only *StudentsID* 1 from my sample data passed.  This is the result from my query, using the data sample, and tested in Access 2010:

```
StudentsID CountOfFailures
---------- ---------------
         1               0
```

If you want to see all students, not just those who passed, simply remove the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: it returns a table of two empty columns. No studentsID no counts . Btw, what does the "q " mean ?

Comment: `q` is just an alias for the table name.  I like it because it's much shorter than the full table name everywhere.  But you don't need to use an alias if you don't like it.

Comment: I removed the "having" line and it works.please edit your answer for the coming rereads.   Many thanks

Comment: Can I filter all the not passed students with the subjects those failed in ?

Comment: Try it!  Post a new question if you run into trouble.